# Why "case" in bash behaves this way?

Tags: bash

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

ENVIRONMENT="production"

case $ENVIRONMENT in
production)
    ENVIRONMENT_NS=prod
    ;;&
staging)
    ENVIRONMENT_NS=staging
    ;;&
development)
    ENVIRONMENT_NS=pga
    ;;
*)
    echo "No matching information found"
esac

echo $ENVIRONMENT_NS
```

```bsh
./test.sh
No matching information found
prod
```

so why "`*)`" option also worked?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `&` at the end of each case block? also if you continue to have trouble matching strings, try putting them in double quotes. eg `"production")`. the reason `*)` fired, is because that is the default case, where any result other than those listed in specific case blocks will go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the "production" clause ends is terminated by `;;&`.

Here's what the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) says about that:

> [...] Using ‘`;;&`’ in place of ‘`;;`’ causes the shell to test
> the patterns in the next clause, if any, and execute any associated
> *command-list* on a successful match, continuing the case statement
> execution as if the pattern list had not matched.

So it matches `production)`, executes that clause (setting `ENVIRONMENT_NS` to "prod"), then looks for additional matching clauses. The default clause, `*)`, also matches (because it matches everything), so it *also* executes that clause (printing "No matching information found").

If you don't want it to execute the default clause in addition to any matching preceding clauses, don't use `;;&`.

Answer (score 2):

> The syntax of the `case` command is:
>
> ```bsh
> case word in
>     [ [(] pattern [| pattern]…) command-list ;;]…
> esac
> ```
>
> […]
>
> There may be an arbitrary number of case clauses, each terminated by a `;;`, `;&`, or `;;&`. The first pattern that matches determines the `command-list` that is executed. […]
>
> If the `;;` operator is used, no subsequent matches are attempted after the first pattern match. […] Using `;;&` in place of `;;` causes the shell to test the patterns in the next clause, if any, and execute any associated `command-list` on a successful match, continuing the case statement execution as if the pattern list had not matched.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs))</sup>

You used `;;&`, not `;;` in the test clause where the pattern is `production`. There was a match, so `ENVIRONMENT_NS=prod` was executed; but because of `;;&` Bash went on "continuing the case statement execution as if the pattern list had not matched". The next matching pattern was `*`.

I think every `;;&` in the code in question should be `;;`.

Side notes:

- POSIX specification of `case` only mentions `;;`. `;;&` is not portable.
- [It's safe not to quote in `case $ENVIRONMENT in`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/108618), but `$ENVIRONMENT_NS` after `echo` [should be double-quoted on principle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).